# Элемент из массива не дублируется

Tags: c#, массивы, классы

Я создал класс:

```
public class Figure
{
    public Point [] Cordinates { get; set; }
    public Figure(Point[] Cordinates)
    {
        this.Cordinates = Cordinates;
    }
}
```

Также сделал массив:

```
 private static Figure[] _figureArray = new Figure[5]
 {
     new Figure(new Point[] {
         new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 0),
         new Point(2, 0), new Point(3, 0)
     },

        ... //Дальше описанны остальные элементы массива
 };
```

Далее я создаю переменную и присваиваю ей элемент массива:

```
 Figure CurrentFigure = _figureArray[0];
```

Если я меняю свойство у данной переменной:

```
 CurrentFigure.Cordinates[0].X = 1;
```

То свойство меняется и у элементов массива.

Скажите пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Comment: Создать другой объект?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Пробовал, не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось реализовать клонирование таким образом

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Figure
        {
            public Point [] Cordinates { get; set; }
            public Figure(Point[] Cordinates)
            {
                this.Cordinates = Cordinates;
            }
            public Figure Clone()
            {
                Figure other = (Figure) this.MemberwiseClone();
                other.Cordinates = new Point[this.Cordinates.Length];
                for (int i=0; i<this.Cordinates.Length; i++){
                    other.Cordinates[i] = new Point(this.Cordinates[i].X,this.Cordinates[i].Y);
                }
                return other;
            }
        }
        private static Figure[] _figureArray = new Figure[2]
            {
             new Figure(new Point[] {
                 new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 0),
                 new Point(2, 0), new Point(3, 0)
             }),
             new Figure(new Point[] {
                 new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 0),
                 new Point(2, 0), new Point(3, 0)
             })
            };
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Figure CurrentFigure = _figureArray[0].Clone();
            CurrentFigure.Cordinates[0].X = 12;
            Console.WriteLine("{0:G}",_figureArray[0].Cordinates[0].X);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:G}",CurrentFigure.Cordinates[0].X);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем уверен в "красоте" данного решения, но оно работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Реализуй метод Клон:

```
class Figure: ICloneable
{
    public Figure Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

и в нужном месте:

```
Figure CurrentFigure = _figureArray[0].Clone();
```

Это случилось по той причине, что автор вопроса не понимает разницы между референс типом и значимым типом данных. Советую почитать об этом детальнее т.к. это важная часть программирования на шарпе.

Comment: Я делал новый метод `Clone()`, и там я просто возвращал новый объект и передавал ему те же аргументы, но это не работало. Данное решение к сожалению тоже